# GWT designer not opening on Eclipse on Linux

Tags: eclipse, gwt, swt, gwt-designer, google-plugin-eclipse

I don't know what the issue with GWT Plugin on eclipse but whenever I'm opening GWT designer on eclipse, I'm getting this issue

> GWT Designer uses the SWT Browser widget to render the GWT UI. SWT
>   Browser requires a compatible xulrunner version installed: it should
>   be 1.9.1.x or 1.9.2.x version and meet the current environment
>   architecture. See http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#whatisbrowser and
>   related topics for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If Zarinfams suggested fix of editing the `eclipse.ini` file and adding `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true` doesn't work;

**Try editing**

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.prefs
```

**change**

```
showIntro=false
```

**to**

```
showIntro=true
```

Eclipse will open showing the intro and the designer tab will work.

NB. This will only work one time since Eclipse will update the file, while ignoring any file permissions you set on the file itself.

You can change the file permissions on the directory at your own risk.

Answer (score -1):

This is SWT web browser problem in eclipse, you can easily solve this problem, I wrote a tutorial for solving this issue in my [weblog](http://saeedzarinfam.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-can-we-run-swt-browser-inside.html).